# JQuery : show time-line like Fire bug

Tags: jquery

I am looking for something to show Time-line like Firebug [image: This]

I just want something shown as in pic with RED rounded circle , not event calender

is there any JQuery plug-in available for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Timeglider**](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/timeglider-impressive-jquery-plugin-for-data-driven-timelines/) is definitely your best option, but what are you trying to accomplish with this exactly? We could give you a better answer with more context. You may be able to write it yourself fairly easily.

[**Here's a good tutorial**](http://tutorialzine.com/2010/01/advanced-event-timeline-with-php-css-jquery/) about how to create a timeline driven event system as well.

Answer (score 1):

there is this plugin called [Timeglider](http://timeglider.com/jquery/), and there is also one using [dojo toolkit](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/12/dojo-charting-widgets-tooltips-and-legend/). hope that helps!